# updating a SQL table based on results from a Sub-Select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, subquery

When I run this SQL code I get the following error message:

```
Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery 
is not introduced with EXISTS.
```

What I want is whenever anything is returned from my update query which has the same `AgreementNo, ElementStartDate and DateSeqNo`, it updates one of those duplicate records with an `ElementStartDate` of + 1 which will remove the duplicate.

```
Update [WASP_Mart_EmbassyActuarial].[dbo].[tblARM_OmegaSource]  
SET ElementStartDate = ElementStartDate + 1  
WHERE AgreementNo IN   
    (SELECT
        count(*) as [Count],
        [AgreementNo],
        [ElementStartDate],
        [DateSeqNo],
        getdate() as Today  
     FROM [WASP_Mart_EmbassyActuarial].[dbo].[tblARM_OmegaSource]   
     GROUP BY  
         [AgreementNo],
         [ElementStartDate],
         [DateSeqNo]  
     HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Comment: But wouldn't this potentially create new duplicates? If e.g. there are two instances of `AgreementNo1, ElementStartDate1, DateSeqNo1` and one instance of `AgreementNo1, ElementStartDate2, DateSeqNo1` where `ElementStartDate2 = ElementStartDate1 + 1`, breaking the duplicate pair using your logic would effectively result in one `AgreementNo1, ElementStartDate1, DateSeqNo1` and two `AgreementNo1, ElementStartDate2, DateSeqNo1`.

Comment: Hi Andriy, I can see where you are coming from. However every record only comes in on the same day each month and therefore by increasing the `ElementStartDate` it is guaranteed there wouldn't be another record for the day + 1. I understand this isn't the best option for what i'm trying to achieve but this is only required for another 3-6 months so i'm really just looking for a quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign row numbers in partitions of `AgreementNo, ElementStartDate, DateSeqNo` and update those rows where the row number is greater than 1:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    ElementStartDate,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AgreementNo, ElementStartDate, DateSeqNo
                                ORDER BY (SELECT 1))  -- actual order probably
                                                      -- doesn't matter here
  FROM WASP_Mart_EmbassyActuarial.dbo.tblARM_OmegaSource
)
UPDATE ranked
SET ElementStartDate = ElementStartDate + rn - 1
WHERE rn > 1
;
```

This method can handle cases with more than two duplicates in a group, although, of course, with very many duplicates it may start producing new ones instead.

Answer (score 1):

The Sub query returning more than one column. You can't compare More than one column using in Operator.

Try below query:

```
Update [WASP_Mart_EmbassyActuarial].[dbo].[tblARM_OmegaSource]  
SET ElementStartDate = ElementStartDate + 1  
WHERE AgreementNo IN   
 ( SELECT [AgreementNo] 
   FROM [WASP_Mart_EmbassyActuarial].[dbo].[tblARM_OmegaSource]   
   GROUP BY  [AgreementNo] -- OR [AgreementNo],[ElementStartDate],[DateSeqNo]
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Update [WASP_Mart_EmbassyActuarial].[dbo].[tblARM_OmegaSource]  
SET ElementStartDate = ElementStartDate + 1  
WHERE AgreementNo IN   
 ( SELECT [AgreementNo] 
   FROM [WASP_Mart_EmbassyActuarial].[dbo].[tblARM_OmegaSource]   
   GROUP BY [AgreementNo],[ElementStartDate],[DateSeqNo]
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)  This is extreamly close however, it updates all the rows that are returned whereas i only want to update the ones which have the same AgreementNo and ElementStartDate and DateSeqNo and just update 1 of the duplicates which will then remove that duplicate value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
Update [WASP_Mart_EmbassyActuarial].[dbo].[tblARM_OmegaSource]  
SET ElementStartDate = ElementStartDate + 1  
WHERE AgreementNo IN   
 (SELECT 
      AgreementNo 
  FROM [WASP_Mart_EmbassyActuarial].[dbo].[tblARM_OmegaSource]   
  GROUP BY 
      [AgreementNo],
      [ElementStartDate],
      [DateSeqNo]
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response it seems to be the same as another post. This is extreamly close however, it updates all the rows that are returned whereas i only want to update the ones which have the same AgreementNo, ElementStartDate and DateSeqNo and just update 1 of the duplicates which will then remove that duplicate value.